# Selective FTP download using .NET

Tags: c#, ftp

I have an ftp build site where new builds will be updated.
It will create a new folder named "Build XXXXX" in a specific ftp location for every new build. I need to download the build from a location inside "Build XXXXX"directory (eg. Builds\Build XXXXX\German\iso\German.iso). Here I can't predict number XXXXX.

I'm planning of writing a .NET application to automatically monitor the ftp location for any new Build XXXXX folder and if it is present, the application should download the file at the specified location (ie \German\iso).

How can I do that. Is there any API available for selectively downloading files.

Also, is there any tools already available to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the methods of the [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be any tool tailor made for your requirement. But if you have the client library, you can make one yourself.