# Deleting the folder and sub folders in FTP server

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I had created folders in FTP server with year, month and date that is after getting logged in to the server we can see a folder created on year when I click on that year it shows month and when I click on month it shows date. Now I need to delete this folder.

Below is my code to delete folder in FTP server

```
FtpWebResponse responseFileDelete = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Can you please help me out to delete a folder.

Comment: can anyone please help me out with this problem

Answer (score 5):

1. The URL you assemble for the `DeleteFile` call is wrong.

   With:

   ```
   path = "ftp://ftp.example.com/" + "/" + ff;
   string server = "ftp://ftp.example.com/";
   ```

   The `ftpURL + "/" + ftpDirectory` is `ftp://ftp.example.com/ftp://ftp.example.com//dir` while you want `ftp://ftp.example.com//dir` or maybe `ftp://ftp.example.com/dir`.

   Use just the `ftpDirectory`

   ```
   FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpDirectory);
   ```

2. You cannot delete a folder with the `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile` anyway. You have to use the [`WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.removedirectory).

   ```
   ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;
   ```

   But note that even the `.RemoveDirectory` can remove an empty directory only.

   You have to recursively delete files and subfolders of the folder first and only then you can delete the folder itself.

   Implementing a recursion using `FtpWebRequest` is not easy, particularly because it does not support the `MLSD` command (what is the only reliable way to distinguish files from folders). For details, see my answer to [C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038676/850848).

   ---

   Alternatively, use another FTP library that supports recursive operations.

   For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), you can use [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles) to delete a folder with its content in a single call:

   ```
   SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
   {
       Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
       HostName = "ftp.example.com",
       UserName = "username",
       Password = "mypassword",
   };

   using (Session session = new Session())
   {
       session.Open(sessionOptions);
       session.RemoveFiles("/" + ff);
   }
   ```

   *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*