# How to download entire folder from ftp in mvc4 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ftp

For that I have used the solution explained in:

[C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038676/c-sharp-download-all-files-and-subdirectories-through-ftp)

But I can not find the permission as explained there: ie.,

```
string permissions = tokens[0];
```

Also I got an error when I tried to download files to downloads .

error:Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\1_IMG_3139.JPG' is denied.

where 1_IMG_3139.JPG is the first image to be downloaded.