# What would be the best method for downloading a a directory recursively?

Tags: c#, download, launcher

Im looking at Nuget packages for my C# project, im unable to find the best method for downloading a remote directory to local. Im also in need of identifying files that do not need to be re downloaded again via time stamping or other methods.

I have been using WGET but it doesn't seem to agree with redirect standard output very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038676/c-sharp-download-all-files-and-subdirectories-through-ftp)

Answer (score 0):

Remote side you could make a program. that grabs the md5 hashsums of all the files. and saves them in an order like

File = Hashsum
Etc

Your program could then download this file lets call it "Hashsums.ini"
Then using the data from the file check if A) the file Exists or B) The hashsums dont add up. if A or B are true. Download the file if not. Move to the next file